# Setting title for navigationItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, navigationitem

I have inserted some view in titleView which is in navigationItem like this `self.navigationItem.titleView=someView;` after this i set it as nil `self.navigationItem.titleView=nil;` then after this i can't set title in navigationItem as `[self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Title"];`.

so how can i set title for navigationItem.give me some idea.

Thanks

Comment: can you show more code. What's happening behind the button. Where are you setting it back to nil? Are you doing this on main thread?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right idea.  According to the docs, setting the titleView to nil should make the title text appear.  I would bet your issue is when in the lifecycle you do that.  I believe adding that code in `viewWillAppear` would be fine.

Comment: after when the page did appear i showing title only .In that page i placed text field and button.when we press that button then i sending the content which is typed in text field to server using rest full web service.During sending time i showed progress bar in the title view of navigation item.so when posting completed then i want to show title again but i cant.how to show title.

Comment: Ok, I understand.  Have you tried calling `SetNeedsDisplay` on the navigationItem?